# Rails remove additional www on subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some security issues with certain subdomains when I have force_ssl enabled in production.rb.

It seems something like https://subdomain.example.com works fine, but I have a client linking to https://www.subdomain.example.com and that www is throwing things off. My routes file is already a bit complex but I'm drawing a blank on how best to handle this redirection. I think I need to check for the number of subdomains present and just remove the first one, right?